# Purpose of 'location', 'position' and 'transform' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

These three tags represent a small number of questions (with [position](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position) having the most at 74), and I'm not really sure what value they add.

The purpose of tags (as far as I am aware) is to organise questions and make it easier for experts of certain topics to find questions to answer. However, I'm not really sure what an expert on 'positions' would know that any other game developer wouldn't (as it's a pretty fundamental concept). The same goes for the other tags, these all seem to be redundant (also I'm not sure I see the difference between location and position).

**Should these tags be removed?**

---

I've just found a potential use of the [location](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/location) tag, a few questions [under](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33796/5404) [that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27941/5404) [tag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23865/5404) are using it to refer to the real-world location of the player (i.e. geolocation). Even though this is very few questions to warrant a tag, I can't think of any other tags that would be a good substitute. Unless there's a suitable alternative, I'll leave these questions as-is.

Comment: For the uses of `location` that you found, `geo-location` would be a better tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[location](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/location) and [position](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position) are stupid and should be removed.

I'm not so sure about [transform](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transform) though. I think there is a legitimate expectation that one could be an export on [transformation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation), as that's basically linear algebra and it's a pretty reasonable "topic" for questions (for example, my favorite question from my computer graphics class: how do you transform a transformation?).

So while the first two should be re-tagged, I think [transform](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transform) should just be made a synonym of [transformation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation).

Comment: Thanks, I suppose you are right about transform being useful - I wasn't particularly sure on that myself. I can set about re-tagging the first two, but I don't have enough rep to suggest a tag-synonym yet.

Comment: The transform to transformation merge is done. The others will need to be manually removed because there is no bulk tag editing feature.

Comment: It might have helped if the big swathe of edit suggestions actually linked this meta post (or even just mentioned it) instead of just saying "Tag cleanup" and then proposing a bunch of changes at odds with the intent of the tag as it was.

Comment: @Alex See MrCranky's comment above; he's right, normally edits that just remove a tag aren't considered substantive enough to approve. If you do this in the future, referring to the meta post in the edit comment will help prevent rejections.

Comment: @MrCranky Sorry my bad, I'll be sure to do that in future. Thanks for letting me know.